# Listing owner with multiple distinct entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following columns:

```
Student Name | Subject
```

How do i list the students having more than one DISTINCT subject registered against him/her?
I am using Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [Student Name]
FROM
  TableName
GROUP BY
  [Student Name]
HAVING
  COUNT(distinct Subject)>1
```